# ERROR: Failed to open apk database: Permission denied when using gitlab sast image for eslint sast

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to install jq and bash in the default sast image provided by gitlab , below is the gitlab ci set up.

```
include:
  - template: SAST.gitlab-ci.yml
eslint-sast:
  stage: test
  allow_failure: false
  before_script:
    - apk update && apk add jq bash
  script: |
  /analyzer run
  cd ci
  bash test-security-password_sast.sh sast
```

This works fine when its using the bandit sast , however when it is using the ESlint image , it gives me this error :

$ apk update && apk add jq bash
ERROR: Unable to lock database: Permission denied
ERROR: Failed to open apk database: Permission denied

How am i supposed to use apk inside this image ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're likely using an image which **restricts its privileges** using the `USER` Docker instruction. Not root means you can't install packages using `apk`.

Gitlab [does **not** currently provide](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2750) a way to override the user set by the image creator.

You may have to roll your own image based on the limiting one (by overriding the `USER` instruction).